# NoStackTraceThrowable Exception is thrown when Postgres DB connectivity is lost

Tags: quarkus, vert.x, quarkus-reactive

Quarkus App - Rest Operation to fetch data from Postgres DB

**Quarkus version : 2.9.0.Final**

Client Lib : **quarkus-reactive-pg-client**

So when the db connection is lost while the service is running and the service receives a request , the app is throwing **NoStackTraceThrowable** exception. This is a generic exception and is preventing from custom handling of db connectivity issue.
Like if u want add DB connect exception to circuit breaker

**How can we get a dedicated exception for db communication issue ?**

Exception :

> ERROR [co.he.da.ex.APIExceptionHandler] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) NoStackTraceThrowable Exception: io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: Fail to read any response from the server, the underlying connection might get lost unexpectedly.

> WARN  [io.qu.re.da.ru.ReactiveDatasourceHealthCheck] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-3) Error obtaining database connection for healthcheck of datasource '': io.vertx.core.impl.NoStackTraceThrowable: Fail to read any response from the server, the underlying connection might get lost unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no other possibility than inspecting the exception message.

Please file an issue to the [sql-client-repo](https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vertx-sql-client) to discuss a possible enhancement.

Comment: updated with exception message , can u have a look

Comment: That's it, if you see "the underlying connection might get lost unexpectedly", it means connectivity has been lost. There's nothing better than inspecting that message so far. Please file an issue for enhancement.